# If statement for current time for both days of week and hours - PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time, status

My interactive map markers are XML/PHP based.

The marker changes dynamically depending on the time on database compared to current time. Its working when I've set it for hours on the database but when I put both hours and days its not working... any idea?

The working example :

```
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE


  $openingHours = explode(";", $row['openingHours']);

  $currentTime = date('H');


  if (in_array($currentTime, $openingHours)) {
      $status = 'Open';
  }
  else {
      $status = 'Closed';
  }
```

But this one is not working :

```
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE

    $days = explode(";", $row['days']);
  $openingHours = explode(";", $row['openingHours']);

  $currentTime = date('D:H');


  if (in_array($currentTime, $days, $openingHours)) {
      $status = 'Open';
  }
  else {
      $status = 'Closed';
  }
```

Comment: your $days having only days and $hours having only hours then how's your if statement will be write. it always goes to else part

Comment: @anantkumarsingh yes, this what happens how can I group days and hours?

Comment: Look at the manual. The third parameter is not for a second array to check. http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php.

Comment: can you put $days and $openingHours array to some extent . not full array and also $currenttime value. then aanyone can help you. just put the array in your question itself.

Comment: I looked @chris85 ,, so how can I do if statement for the 3 parameters all together.. ?

Comment: The array is imported from the database, the database is filled-out from an HTML form!

Comment: The days dont seem to correlate to the hours in any way I can see..

Comment: if (in_array($currentTime, $days, $openingHours = true)) {
   $status = 'Open';


Same thing...

Comment: Yes, as stated `in_array` only checks **one value** against **one array**. One way would be to have the hours and the days in the table together. It'd be a 7 row table; Column 1 days, column 2 opentime, column 3, closedtime. Then when you want to query `select * from timestable where day = ? and ? between opentime and closetime`. Placeholder 1 would be the day, placeholder 2 the time.